# add 2 value to a div and then spliting?

Tags: html, jquery

Not sure if this is the best way but, as can see below I am getting the current page and adding it to the div of "load_more" I then use this value in a function to + 1. however I now need another value added to this "total pages" and I am not sure where to add it do (another div). Can I add it to the div (the same one on click) also then slit out the results? in the load more click function?

Thanks

gets the value

```
  $('.load_more').live("click", function(){ //When user clicks

            var currentPage = parseInt($(this).attr('id'), 10);
            ++currentPage;

            alert(currentPage);

            dosomething(currentPage);
        });
```

set the value

```
var currentPage = "";
var totalPages = ";"

 $.each(r.MESSAGES, function(key, value){

     currentPage += value.CURRENTPAGE;
     totalPages += value.TOTALPAGES;                        

 })
jQuery('.load_more').attr("id", currentPage);
```

html

```
<div id="load-more">
    <a class="load_more" id="123" href="#">
        Load More
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding DOM attributes to your class `load_more` it can be an idea using jQuery data storage. http://api.jquery.com/data/

Very simple to use: http://jsfiddle.net/j3bb5/

```
$('.load_more').data("current_page", 1); // Setting variable current_page;
alert( $('.load_more').data("current_page") ); // Getting variable current_page, alerts "1"
```

And you can store Objects as well: http://jsfiddle.net/j3bb5/1/

```
$('.load_more').data("current_page", { // Setting variable current_page;
    id: 1,
    name: "My page 1"
}); // Setting variable current_page;
alert( $('.load_more').data("current_page").id ); // Getting variable current_page, alerts "1"
alert( $('.load_more').data("current_page").name ); // Getting variable current_page, alerts "My page 1"
```

And now to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/j3bb5/4/

Don't know what variable `r` is but something like this?

```
var r = {
    MESSAGES: [{
        CURRENTPAGE: 1,
        TOTALPAGES: 4
    },{
        CURRENTPAGE: 2,
        TOTALPAGES: 4
    }]
};
```

Function `doSomething` does nothing ;)

```
function doSomething(CURRENTPAGE, TOTALPAGES) {};
```

Setting the values from `r.MESSAGES` using `jQuery.fn.data` method

First we define our temporary `CURRENTPAGE` and `TOTALPAGES` variables

```
var CURRENTPAGE = 0, TOTALPAGES = 0;
```

Loops throw `r.MESSAGES` and updating `CURRENTPAGE` and `TOTALPAGES`

```
$.each(r.MESSAGES, function(key, value) {
    CURRENTPAGE += value.CURRENTPAGE;
    TOTALPAGES += value.TOTALPAGES;
});
```

Binds them to the selector `.load_more`

```
$('.load_more').data("CURRENTPAGE", CURRENTPAGE);
$('.load_more').data("TOTALPAGES", TOTALPAGES);
```

Click Event on `.load_more`

```
$('.load_more').live("click", function() {
```

Getting `CURRENTPAGE` and `TOTALPAGES` from `data` method:

```
    var CURRENTPAGE = $(this).data("CURRENTPAGE");
    var TOTALPAGES = $(this).data("TOTALPAGES");
```

Alerting the values:

```
    alert("CURRENTPAGE: " + CURRENTPAGE);
    alert("TOTALPAGES: " + TOTALPAGES);
```

And now increases the values by one: Note the double + sign before our variables. It means you  add one to the value. Se a little deeper explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/j3bb5/6/

```
    $(this).data("CURRENTPAGE", ++CURRENTPAGE);
    $(this).data("TOTALPAGES", ++TOTALPAGES);

    doSomething(CURRENTPAGE, TOTALPAGES);
});
```

Comment: this is amazing! thanks so much really helped! did not know about using the jQuery data storage, cool!